# RxSwift: Zip Observables only if requirements are met

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift, reactivex

Imagine a user profile which allows editing of fields like *name*, *surname*, *age* and *avatarImage*. When the user clicks `Save`, requests are sent for each value that has been changed.

Now please think of functions with signatures like those:

```
func rx_updateUserName(name: String) -> Observable<UpdateUserNameResponse>
func rx_updateSurname(surname: String) -> Observable<UpdateSurnameResponse>
func rx_updateAge(age: Int) -> Observable<UpdateAgeResponse>
```

Normally we would just `zip` those requests like this:

```
let nameReqObservable = rx_updateUserName("Gandalf")
let surnameReqObservable = rx_updateSurname("The White")
let ageReqObservable = rx_updateAge(123)

let zippedRequests = Observable.zip(nameReqObservable, surnameReqObservable, ageReqObservable, 
    resultSelector: { (userNameResponse, surnameResponse, areResponse) in

    return (userNameResponse, surnameResponse, areResponse)
}).subscribeNext(...)
```

What should I do when I only want to perform the requests for the values that changed?

Comment: Are you saying that when save is hit you have three fields that each generate one value?

Comment: When save is hit, I want to preselect the requests that have to be made, based on the checks if name, surname or age have changed.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I wanted to know if when you hit save you have three observables each producing one value?

Comment: Each one produces its own value, yes.

Comment: That is a little weird. Why not just have one observable that produces all three values at the same time and avoid all of the zipping you're doing? After all, it's based on a single event of the save button being hit.

Comment: You are somewhat right. The problem is, that I need to wait for every web-request, that I make when hitting save, to finish.

Comment: Are you saying that you have to make separate web requests to save each field?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.combineLatest()`?
Visualization here - http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest
In your case, whenever there is a value changed in one of the input observables, the `combinedRequests` observable will emit a new set of inputs.

```
let combinedRequests = Observable.combineLatest(nameReqObservable, surnameReqObservable, ageReqObservable, 
    resultSelector: { (userNameResponse, surnameResponse, ageResponse) in

    return (userNameResponse, surnameResponse, ageResponse)
}).subscribeNext(...)
```

Doc from RxSwift, `.combineLatest()`:

> Merges the specified observable sequences into one observable sequence by using the selector function whenever any of the observable sequences produces an element.

Comment: So do you suggest to do the check if the request is necessary in the according observable itself?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I fully understood your question. Think of it this way, imagine your 3 requests are 3 observable streams. Each stream will emits an element whenever the response value is changed. So whenever any of these 3 streams emits an element, `combineLatest()` - an observable itself - will emit an element that contain all 3 elements from the 3 streams.

Comment: It's up to you to make the value changed requests whether it's 1 or 3 of them... the combined observable simply combines the new responses with its old responses from other streams, then emits.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a solution for my problem, because I need to find a way to easily preselect and combine the remaining requests.